# Python | Is it possible to have multiple outcomes of one IF statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

Making an IT quiz for school and I don't want it to be case sensitive, so I'd have 2 if statements if I want there to be 2 possible answers. My problem is that only one answer works.. May sound confusing.

```
a = input("And the answer is...")

if a == "answer1":
   print("Correct!")

if a == "answer2":
   print("Correct!")

else:
    print("Incorrect!")
```

The outcome if you enter "answer1" is:

```
Correct!
Incorrect!
```

However, "answer2" will give you:

```
Correct!
```

Basically, I want both "answer1" and "answer2" to have the outcome of "Correct!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of different ways:

```
if a == "answer1" or a == "answer2":
  print("Correct!")
else:
  print("Incorrect!")
```

or

```
if a in ["answer1", "answer2"]:
  print("Correct!")
else:
  print("Incorrect!")
```

or

```
if a == "answer1":
  print("Correct!")
elif a == "answer2":
  print("Correct!")
else:
  print("Incorrect!")
```

You can read more about in the ["Flow Control"](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/controlflow.html) section of the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

While isowen's answer is correct, and is a better way of writing the function, it doesn't explain why the first one is wrong.

The actual problem is that the else only applies to the second if statement, not the first one. If you wanted to have different behavior for each case, you could do:

```
a = input("And the answer is...")

if a == "answer1":
    print("Correct!")

elif a == "answer2":
    print("Also Correct!")

else:
    print("Incorrect!")
```

edit: isowen wasn't done yet when I wrote this.